# How to send HTTPHeader using QT WebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtwebengine, webengine

I was playing around with QT WebEngine to make a desktop web browser which suits my requirements while working. Unfortunately, I need send some data with the HTTP Header to a site. I came across [QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestinfo.html) class' `void QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo::setHttpHeader(const QByteArray &name, const QByteArray &value)` method but I don't really know how to use it in code. This is my code so far:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240
    title: qsTr("Browser")
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "some http url here"
        Rectangle{
            height: 100
            width: height
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine/qtwebengineglobal.h>
#include <QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo>
#include <QByteArray>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QByteArray key, value;
    key.append("SomeKey");
    value.append("SomeValue");
    QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo url;//Won't work because its constructor is private
    url.setHttpHeader(key, value);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Since the above code throws an error, I really can't figure out a fix for this problem. TIA

Answer (score 1):

This is my tiny [project](https://bitbucket.org/visualgui823/minibrowser/src/9bfab6e9b8fc24417dedbdfe9670142cf9afd004/minibrowser.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) using webengine, FYI.

```
view->page()->profile()->setRequestInterceptor(/*instance inerit QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor*/)
...
void /*class inerit WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor*/::interceptRequest(QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo &info)
{
    info.setHttpHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
}
```