# PyQt WebEngine set http headers

Tags: pyqt, http-headers, qtwebengine

I want to port my app from **Qt WebKit** to **Qt WebEngine**. In Qt Webkit I can set http headers by using QNetworkRequest, but in Qt WebEngine, the doc says:

> Qt WebEngine has its own HTTP implementation and cannot go through a QNetworkAccessManager

I use PyQt5 and Qt5.8.

I cannot find how to set http headers in Qt WebEngine.

--------------update----------------

Finally, it worked! Thanks! @Trilarion:

define my QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor class

```
class NWUrlRequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor):
    def __init__(self, headers):
        super(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor, self).__init__()
        self.headers = headers

    def set_headers(self,headers):
        self.headers = headers

    def interceptRequest(self, info):
        print info, self.headers
        for header, value in self.headers:
            info.setHttpHeader(header, value);
```

use in my browser:

```
self.request_interceptor = NWUrlRequestInterceptor(self.headers)
self.webpage.profile().setRequestInterceptor(self.request_interceptor)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement a [QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor.html) in whose interceptRequest method you get a QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo which can set a http header via `setHttpHeader`.

Set the request interceptor via QWebEngineView.page().profile().setRequestInterceptor.

Inspired by [How to send HTTPHeader using QT WebEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684517/how-to-send-httpheader-using-qt-webengine).