# How to intercept response headers in QWebEnginePage

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebenginepage

I try to intercept response headers of displayed page in QWebEnginePage.

I have saw this post [Capture server response with QWebEngineView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309105/capture-server-response-with-qwebengineview), but only URL is returned.

So is there a way to retrive response header in QWebEngine? Or if not is there an alternative solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684517/how-to-send-httpheader-using-qt-webengine